extract event pairs from multiline text
I would like to extract event pair (start and end marked by + and -). but the pairs maybe not match which means start happen two times then followed the end event.
In below example, event B start happed 2 times, so I wish it output a mismatched pair with nil in the end event not found.
import re
import pandas as pd

data = """
00:00:00 +running A
dummy data
00:00:01 -running
00:00:02 +running B
dummy data
00:00:03 +running B
00:00:04 -running
00:00:05 +running C
dummy data
00:00:06 -running
00:00:07 +running D
10:00:08 -running


"""
m = re.findall(r"(\d+:\d+:\d+) \+running (\w+).*?(\d+:\d+:\d+) \-running",data,re.DOTALL)
print(len(m))
df = pd.DataFrame(m,columns=['ts1','name','ts2'])
print(df)


Current output:
        ts1 name       ts2
0  00:00:00    A  00:00:01
1  00:00:02    B  00:00:04
2  00:00:05    C  00:00:06
3  00:00:07    D  10:00:08


Expected:
        ts1 name       ts2
0  00:00:00    A  00:00:01
1  00:00:02    B  NA
2  00:00:03    B  00:00:04
3  00:00:05    C  00:00:06
4  00:00:07    D  10:00:08


What's proper way to get such results in python? I do not care about if use findall or not.

You can just modify your regex to have an optional trailing part:
data = """
00:00:00 +running A
dummy data
00:00:01 -running
00:00:02 +running B
dummy data
00:00:03 +running B
00:00:04 -running
00:00:05 +running C
dummy data
00:00:06 -running
00:00:07 +running D
10:00:08 -running
"""

m = re.findall(r"(\d+:\d+:\d+) \+running (\w+)(?:\n(\d+:\d+:\d+) \-running)?",
               data, re.DOTALL)
df = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=['ts1','name','ts2']).replace('', None)

NB. replacing .*? by \n.
Output:
        ts1 name       ts2
0  00:00:00    A  00:00:01
1  00:00:02    B      None
2  00:00:03    B  00:00:04
3  00:00:05    C  00:00:06
4  00:00:07    D  10:00:08

regex demo
Handling dummy data
If you assume there could be arbitrary rows of data you could filter them out if they don't match the expected pattern:
data = """
00:00:00 +running A
dummy data
00:00:01 -running
00:00:02 +running B
dummy data
00:00:03 +running B
00:00:04 -running
00:00:05 +running C
dummy data
00:00:06 -running
00:00:07 +running D
10:00:08 -running
"""

m = re.findall(r"(\d+:\d+:\d+) \+running (\w+)(?:\s*(\d+:\d+:\d+) \-running)?",
               '\n'.join(x for x in data.splitlines() if
                         re.match(r'\d+:\d+:\d+ [-+]running', x)),
               re.DOTALL)
df = pd.DataFrame(m,columns=['ts1','name','ts2']).replace('', None)

Or using a negative lookahead to handle the dummy part:
m = re.findall(r"(\d+:\d+:\d+) \+running (\w+)(?:(?:.(?!\d+:\d+:\d+))*\n(\d+:\d+:\d+) \-running)?",
               data, re.DOTALL)
df = pd.DataFrame(m,columns=['ts1','name','ts2']).replace('', None)

regex demo
Output:
        ts1 name       ts2
0  00:00:00    A  00:00:01
1  00:00:02    B      None
2  00:00:03    B  00:00:04
3  00:00:05    C  00:00:06
4  00:00:07    D  10:00:08


Awesome, but if some dummy data in between, this regex can not handle it. any suggestion to improve it? I have update sample data in my question as well.

@lucky1928 can you tell me more about the dummy data? Does it contains numbers, special characters, etc?

Try:
import re

import pandas as pd

data = """

00:00:00 +running A
dummy data
00:00:01 -running
00:00:02 +running B
dummy data
00:00:03 +running B
00:00:04 -running
00:00:05 +running C
dummy data
00:00:06 -running
00:00:07 +running D
10:00:08 -running



"""


def get_columns(data):
    stack = []
    for time, val in data:
        if val.startswith("+"):
            stack.append((time, val.split()[-1]))
        elif val.startswith("-") and stack:
            t, v = stack.pop()
            yield t, v, time

    for time, val in stack:
        yield time, val, None


all_data = []
for line in map(str.strip, data.splitlines()):
    if not re.match(r"\d+:\d+:\d+", line):
        continue
    all_data.append(line.split(maxsplit=1))

df = pd.DataFrame(get_columns(all_data), columns=["ts1", "name", "ts2"]).sort_values(
    "ts1"
)
print(df)

Prints:
        ts1 name       ts2
0  00:00:00    A  00:00:01
4  00:00:02    B      None
1  00:00:03    B  00:00:04
2  00:00:05    C  00:00:06
3  00:00:07    D  10:00:08

EDIT: Added re check that line must start with time pattern.
